# устранение неверно распознанных объектов детектором

Tags: c++, opencv

я работаю с opencv детекторами объектов на с++ и у меня возникла проблема, при обнаружении объектов вместе с нужными, происходит детекция ненужны, таких как дождь, блики солнца в воде, листочки на деревьях движущиеся. как это можно устранить? пробовалось сохранить траекторию и координаты, но часть таких ненужных объектов все равно остается.

Answer (score 0):

Для устранения неверно распознанных объектов детектором, можно применить несколько подходов:

1. Использование более точного моделирования объектов: Попробуйте использовать более сложные модели или алгоритмы, которые могут лучше различать нужные объекты от нежелательных. Некоторые модели, такие как [Cascade Classifier](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html) или [SSD (Single Shot MultiBox Detector)](https://medium.com/featurepreneur/object-detection-using-single-shot-multibox-detection-ssd-and-opencvs-deep-neural-network-dnn-d983e9d52652), могут быть более подходящими для определенных типов объектов.
2. Использование более точных и обученных наборов данных: Для обучения детекторов вам может потребоваться больший и более разнообразный набор данных, чтобы детекторы могли лучше различать объекты, которые вам нужны. Обучение на большем количестве примеров может помочь снизить число ложных срабатываний.
3. Фильтрация по времени и пространству: Если ненужные объекты имеют некоторые характеристики, которые отличают их от нужных, можно применить фильтрацию объектов на основе их пространственного и временного расположения. Например, можно игнорировать объекты, которые появляются только в определенные моменты времени или находятся за пределами определенного диапазона координат.
4. Использование методов отслеживания объектов: Если нежелательные объекты движутся по определенным траекториям или имеют определенные закономерности движения, можно применить методы отслеживания объектов, чтобы убедиться, что только нужные объекты сохраняются после детекции. Например, можно использовать алгоритмы отслеживания, такие как [Kalman Filter](https://codingcorner.org/kalman-filter-cpp-eigen-cmake/) или [Particle Filter](https://ricoruotongjia.medium.com/an-easy-to-implement-face-tracker-using-particle-filtering-part-2-951ee80872a4), чтобы предсказать и отслеживать движение объектов на основе предыдущих кадров.
5. Тонкая настройка параметров детектора: Иногда простая настройка параметров детектора может помочь снизить ложные срабатывания. Это может включать в себя изменение пороговых значений, установку минимальных размеров объектов или настройку других параметров алгоритма.

Попробуйте комбинировать и адаптировать эти методы для вашей конкретной задачи и типа объектов, чтобы снизить количество неверных срабатываний детектора.

Comment: Ещё поищите информацию про "усложненные каскады хаара" (Haar cascades) и YOLO

Comment: спасибо, нейронные сети в работе не использую. На обстальное внимание обращу